# Why do I get the pylint error: Module 'socket' has no 'gethostname' member (no-member)?

Tags: python, sockets, python-import, pylint

I have the following code example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
'''Why do I get the pylint error Module 'socket' has no 'gethostname' member (no-member)?'''
import socket
print(socket.gethostname())
```

Which runs fine and prints the hostname as output.

However, when I check with pylint I get an error:

```
% pylint testSocket.py
************* Module testSocket
testSocket.py:7:6: E1101: Module 'socket' has no 'gethostname' member (no-member)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at -15.00/10 (previous run: -20.00/10, +5.00)

%
```

This is a super-trimmed down example. In my full-fledged code I play with other socket functions such as `socket.getfqdn()`, or `socket.gethostbyname(nDict['HOST_FQDN'])` with no pylint issues.

Even within the socket module it includes the following line under Functions:

```
    gethostname() -- return the current hostname
```

How can I get a clean run of pylint? (Without resorting to # pylint: disable=E1101)

Python 3.8.2, pylint 2.7.2

Comment: do you have another file name socket.py or a socket folder with init.py? (I dont fail my pylint with this same code)

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with some environment (MacOs for example) in pylint right now. As a workaround, if you install your environment with `pyenv`, it will recompile some package and works. See [this comment](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/4759#issuecomment-890559512)

> When I first stumbled over this I made a list to check what the culprits are, and it boiled down to two modules: `socket (socket.error, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)`, `math (math.log10, math.pi, math.ceil, math.sqrt)`

> For example, the math.log10 is found in math.pyi (i.e. the stub file) when using command+SHIFT to jump to source.
> Maybe those stub files are not installed correctly with some installation methods.
> I'll try to figure out where they should live - if I jump from VScode to the .pyi file, it opens one of the fallback stub files provided by the Pylance plugin for VScode.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to `pyenv`. It's a nice tool to know about. I tried implementing it, but without success. I'm not sure if I failed to configure `pyenv` correctly or if it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @shepster try using pip3 install pylint.  I've had the same problem was installing pylint via pip worked (although this may not be the the recommended way of fixing this issue)